# Changed event for JavaScript Binding in Qml?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a property which is defined by a JavaScript expression (`currentContainer`):

```
Item {
    id: theContainer

    property alias currentIndex: theListView.currentIndex
    signal onCurrentIndexChanged()

    property MyCustomCppContainer currentContainer: {
        if(theListView.currentIndex >= 0)
            theModel.getCustomContainer(theListView.currentIndex)
        else
            null
    }
    signal onCurrentContainerChanged() // nobody calls this signal (yet)

    MyCustomCppModel {
        id: theModel
    }

    ListView {
        id: theListView

        anchors.fill: parent

        model: theModel
        currentIndex: -1
        onCurrentIndexChanged: theContainer.onCurrentIndexChanged()

        /* Other properties stripped for example */
    }
}
```

Sadly I always get the last selected container, not the currently selected one:

```
ContainerItem {
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        //On first change, currentContainer is null
        //though the first one was selected

        //After selecting the second entry
        //I get the result I expected last time

        console.log(currentContainer.name);
    }
}
```

I think a solution would be to have another signal for `currentContainer`: `onCurrentContainerChanged()`.

But who calls this special signal?

Comment: What do you use the signals `onCurrentContainerChanged` (handler: `onOnCurrentContainerChanged`) and `onCurrentIndexChanged` (handler `onOnCurrentIndexChanged`) for?

Comment: I want to modify an interactive map accordingly to the currently selected item. The map itself is a custom QPainter based item. It only supports methods to add and remove highlightings so I cannot simply use databinding here.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code in the binding: `property MyCustomCppContainer currentContainer: [...]` with `console.log(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this using a C++ helper class:

```
class PropertyChangedHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant theProperty WRITE setTheProperty NOTIFY thePropertyChanged)

public:
    PropertyChangedHelper(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~PropertyChangedHelper() {}

    void setTheProperty(QVariant) {
        Q_EMIT thePropertyChanged();
    }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void thePropertyChanged();

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(PropertyChangedHelper)
};
```

Usage is quite simple:

```
PropertyChangedHelper {
    theProperty: containerItem.currentContainer
    onThePropertyChanged: {
        console.log(containerItem.currentContainer.name);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this violates any Qml/QtQuick philosophies, but it works.

Comment: You might do this, but you can do it directly in QML, so - why?

Comment: Maybe you should read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-attributes - for each property you create, an `[property]Changed`-signal is implicitly created. The corresponding handler is as always: `on[Property]Changed`

Comment: Ah I missed that! QtCreator did not autocomplete correctly and so I thought there is no signal. You answered my question with your comment!